Godot on signal trigger external animation
It may not matter, but I'm following How to make a Video Game - Godot Beginner Tutorial. I want to implement the dying animation instead of removing CollisionShape2D from the body (parameter passed to Area2D's _on_body_entered signal).
The player:

The player animations:

The code to remove the CollisionShape2D (player falls off the screen before restarting, based on tutorial) that works:
func _on_body_entered(body):
    print("You die")
    Engine.time_scale = 0.5
    body.get_node("CollisionShape2D").queue_free()
    timer.start()

What I've tried to get dying animation to play:
func _on_body_entered(body):
    print("You die")
    var player_anim = body.get_node("AnimatedSprite2D") # tried a single line as well
    Engine.time_scale = 0.5
    player_anim.play("dying" )
    timer.start()

I get no errors, it just resets after the designated amount of time. Is it possible to trigger player dying animation from Area2D script?

The player character has code that plays other animations, does it not? So you play the "dying" animation from here, but then the code in the player character plays another animation instead.

So I ended up adding a variable is_dead on player that I then set that from _on_body_entered
func _on_body_entered(body):
    print("You die")
    body.is_dead = true
    #body.get_node("CollisionShape2D").queue_free()
    timer.start()

Player
var is_dead = false
func _physics_process(delta):
    if is_dead:
        animated_sprite.play('dying')
    elif velocity.y != 0:
      # ....

